# Parallel processing image analyzer function in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, parallel-processing

I have created a function, **`imgs_to_df()`** (which relies on `img_to_vec()`) that takes a list of URLs that point to a JPG (e.g. https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/48123413937_54bb53e98b_o.jpg), resizes it, and converts the URLs to a dataframe of RGB values, where each row is a different image, and each column is the R, G, or B value of the pixel of the (resized) image.

However, the function is very slow, especially once it gets into lists of hundreds or thousands of links, so I need a way to parallelize or otherwise make the process much, much faster. I'd also like to ensure there is a way to easily to match the URLs back with the RGB vectors after I'm done.
[image]
I am very new to parallel processing and everything I have read is just confusing me even more.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def img_to_vec(jpg_url, resize=True, new_width=300, new_height=300):
    """ Takes a URL of an image, resizes it (optional), and converts it to a 
        vector representing RGB values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    jpg_url: String. A URL that points to a JPG image.
    resize: Boolean. Default True. Whether image should be resized before calculating RGB.
    new_width: Int. Default 300. New width to convert image to before calculating RGB.
    new_height: Int. Default 300. New height to conver image to before calculating RGB.

    Returns
    -------
    rgb_vec: Vector of size 3*new_width*new_height for the RGB values in each pixel of the image.


    """
    response = requests.get(jpg_url) # Create remote image connection
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) # Save image connection (NOT actual image)
    if resize:
        img = img.resize((new_width, new_height)) 
    rgb_img = np.array(img) # Create matrix of RGB values
    rgb_vec = rgb_img.ravel() # Flatten 3D matrix of RGB values to a vector
    return rgb_vec   



# Consider parallel processing here
def imgs_to_df(jpg_urls, common_width=300, common_height=300):
    """ Takes a list of jpg_urls and converts it to a dataframe of RGB values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    jpg_urls: A list of jpg_urls to be resized and converted to a dataframe of RGB values.
    common_width: Int. Default 300. New width to convert all images to before calculating RGB.
    common_height: Int. Default 300. New height to convert all images to before calculating RGB.

    Returns
    -------
    rgb_df: Pandas dataframe of dimensions len(jpg_urls) rows and common_width*common_height*3
        columns. Each row is a unique jpeg image, and each column is an R/G/B value of 
        a particular pixel of the resized image


    """
    assert common_width>0 and common_height>0, 'Error: invalid new_width or new_height dimensions'
    for url_idx in range(len(jpg_urls)):
        if url_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Converting url number {urlnum} of {urltotal} to RGB '.format(urlnum=url_idx, urltotal=len(jpg_urls)))
        try:  
            img_i = img_to_vec(jpg_urls[url_idx])
            if url_idx == 0:
                vecs = img_i
            else: 
                try:
                    vecs = np.vstack((vecs, img_i))
                except:
                    vecs = np.vstack((vecs, np.array([-1]*common_width*common_height*3)))
                    print('Warning: Error in converting {error_url} to RGB'.format(error_url=jpg_urls[url_idx]))

        except:
            vvecs = np.vstack((vecs, np.array([-1]*common_width*common_height*3)))
            print('Warning: Error in converting {error_url} to RGB'.format(error_url=jpg_urls[url_idx]))

    rgb_df = pd.DataFrame(vecs)
    return rgb_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ThreadPool as your task is I/O bound.

I'm using `concurrent.futures`. Your function needs to be re-written so that it takes a single URL and makes it to a `df`.

I added two snippets, one just simply uses loops and another uses Threading. The second one is much much faster.

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def img_to_vec(jpg_url, resize=True, new_width=300, new_height=300):
    """ Takes a URL of an image, resizes it (optional), and converts it to a 
        vector representing RGB values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    jpg_url: String. A URL that points to a JPG image.
    resize: Boolean. Default True. Whether image should be resized before calculating RGB.
    new_width: Int. Default 300. New width to convert image to before calculating RGB.
    new_height: Int. Default 300. New height to conver image to before calculating RGB.

    Returns
    -------
    rgb_vec: Vector of size 3*new_width*new_height for the RGB values in each pixel of the image.


    """
    response = requests.get(jpg_url) # Create remote image connection
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) # Save image connection (NOT actual image)
    if resize:
        img = img.resize((new_width, new_height)) 
    rgb_img = np.array(img) # Create matrix of RGB values
    rgb_vec = rgb_img.ravel() # Flatten 3D matrix of RGB values to a vector
    return rgb_vec   



# Consider parallel processing here
def imgs_to_df(jpg_url, common_width=300, common_height=300):

    assert common_width>0 and common_height>0, 'Error: invalid new_width or new_height dimensions'

    try:  
        img_i = img_to_vec(jpg_url)
        vecs = img_i

        try:
            vecs = np.vstack((vecs, img_i))
        except:
            vecs = np.vstack((vecs, np.array([-1]*common_width*common_height*3)))
            print('Warning: Error in converting {error_url} to RGB'.format(error_url=jpg_urls[url_idx]))

    except:
        print('failed')

    rgb_df = pd.DataFrame(vecs)
    return rgb_df

img_urls = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/1200px-Flower_poster_2.jpg', 'https://www.tiltedtulipflorist.com/assets/1/14/DimFeatured/159229xL_HR_fd_3_6_17.jpg?114702&value=217',
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/1200px-Flower_poster_2.jpg', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a5/Flower_poster_2.jpg/1200px-Flower_poster_2.jpg']

import time
t1 = time.time()
dfs = []
for iu in img_urls:
    df = imgs_to_df(iu)
    dfs.append(df)
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
print(dfs)

# aprroach with multi-threading

import concurrent.futures

t1 = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    dfs = [df for df in executor.map(imgs_to_df, img_urls)]

t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
print(dfs)
```

**Out:**

```
3.540484666824341
[   0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     255     255     255     255  ...      93     155     119      97
1     255     255     255     255  ...      93     155     119      97

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns]]
1.2170848846435547
[   0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     255     255     255     255  ...      93     155     119      97
1     255     255     255     255  ...      93     155     119      97

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns],    0       1       2       3       ...  269996  269997  269998  269999
0     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243
1     240     240     237     251  ...     247     243     243     243

[2 rows x 270000 columns]]
```

Comment: Could you explain WHY do you think a **ThreadPool**-based execution will be beneficial, given the Python (as-is in 2020/2Q) still uses central GIL-lock re-[SERIAL]-isation of the flow of code-execution ( across all such threads ) that they finally appear to get as a pure-[SERIAL] flow, paying all the costs of maintaining the GIL-based switching, yet having zero performance benefit from doing so? Latency masking may be beneficial, yet only for systems, that permit O/S-scheduler to run multiple threads on multi-core silicon. Not the Python, that avoids any&all [CONCURRENT]-events by the GIL-lock

Comment: I assume OP didn't actually ask why something will work so I didn't get into any explanation. By the rule of thumb, I know if a process is I/O bound, running it asynchronously will result in smaller execution time in most cases. Yes, there are cases where the multi-threading doesn't result in better speed, but in OP's example, it must improve the speed. Can you educate me on why do you think multi-threading will not work here? So far from my knowledge, it seems it should work and from some benchmarks that I ran, it works!